# How do I right align my string? in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've got this so far and I was having a problem with getting the output to print right aligned.

I've tried using `.rjust` to make my output show up like this:

```
        abc
         de
  fghijklmn
```

but it shows up like this:

```
abc
de
fghijklmn
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
strings = ['abc', 'de', 'fghijklmn']
col_umn = ("\n".join(strings))
rcol_umn = (col_umn.rjust(max(len(ele) for ele in strings)))
width = max(len(ele) for ele in strings)
fillchar = " "
print(col_umn.rjust(5, fillchar))
length = max(strings)
res = max(len(ele) for ele in strings)
print(" ")
print(str(res))
```

Comment: You need to justify *each individual string*, not all of the strings joined together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can format your string to be padded and aligned inside an f-string. In this case i use the `>` to donate right aligned and use the value of `longest` to tell it how much to pad/align it by

```py
strings = ['abc', 'de', 'fghijklmn']
longest = len(max(strings, key=len))
print("\n".join([f"{string: >{longest}}" for string in strings]))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
      abc
       de
fghijklmn
```